# Angular $http not working as expected

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to angular and trying to consume a basic back end service that I created using laravel. It is a basic Todo application and I am trying to fetch all the users resource for now.

If you go to the following URI, it will give back the all the users in the application:

[Link to the URI](http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users)

The code in my angular file looks like

```
var testing = angular.module('testing', []);

testing.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.hello = "Hello World!";
    $http.get('users.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.users = data;
    });
});
```

Now when I pass the URI in the parameter of `$http.get` method, I don't see any data. I have tried `{{ users | json }}` in my main index file to see the dump output. It simply doesn't work. But when I copy just the data array in the response and save it to a json file, it works perfectly.

Now the json that is returned from the web service has slightly more information like status and messages. How do I remove them when fetching them in Angular so that it works or is there a way I can have them returned and then extract them somehow from the whole data that has been returned?

Comment: is success callback function executes ?

Comment: I think it does. Because when I am using the json file, it returns all the data.

Comment: The URL you gave us is `http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users`. So why are you using `users.json`? There is no `.json`in the working URL.

Comment: users.json is a file that I created locally to check if it fetching the data without the status and messages. The users.json file only contains the data array copied from the actual response.

Comment: So, what exactly is the code that doesn't work? Because you're saying that it works fine with the JSON file in your question, and the posted code gets data from users.json, which is the JSON file.

Comment: Okay I will try clearing this up, it is slightly hard to explain. The response for the URI I gave is not working but when I copy the data part of the response and leave the status part and messages part and put it in a json file locally it works. Similarly when I try to copy paste the whole response in the local json file and try fetching it, it doesn't work. Which means that the response from the web that has status and messages in it, is creating some problem.

Comment: You should provide the actual code you try, the actual content of the file you're trying to access, and define what you mean by "doesn't work". A plunkr or jsfiddle would help.

Comment: I would second with @JBNizet, a plunkr would be helpful in debugging this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If here http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users is response from your server you should update your $http call to :

```
 $http.get('users.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.users = response.data;
    });
```

if you requesting json file from your local iis make sure that it can serve .json files